# how to qsort dynamically allocated 2d char array

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, qsort

I am trying to qsort a dynamically-allocated 2d array, without success.  I assume it has something to do with the dynamic allocation, because things work fine if I use a global 2d array (eg, fileList[148096][100]).  Any ideas?

```
// global:
char **fileList;

void allocateFileListArray(void)
{
  int arraySize = 148096;
  int fileNameLength = 100;

  /*  allocate storage for an array of pointers */
  fileList = (char **) malloc(arraySize * sizeof(char *));

  /* for each pointer, allocate storage for an array of chars */
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
  {
      if ((fileList[i] = (char *) malloc(fileNameLength * sizeof(char))) == NULL)
          printf("failed fileList alloc\n");
    }
}

void sortTheArray(int fileListCount)
{
    qsort (( char * ) fileList, fileListCount, sizeof ( *fileList ), 
     (compfn) compareStrings );
}



 int compareStrings(char *stackA, char *stackB)
 {
    int result;

    result = strcmp( stackA->name, stackB->name);

    return(result);

}
```

Comment: What is your definition of sorting a 2D array? You probably want to sort rows... then pass the appropriate compare function on them...

Comment: You don't declare `fileListIndex`. Just a guess, but you're computing it with `(sizeof(fileList) / sizeof(*fileList))` which is correct in the fixed-size array type but not with the dynamically allocated array.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? BTW could you please add the definition for compareStrings(). Also: none of the casts in the fragment are needed. Drop them.

Comment: By sorting a 2d array I mean sort so the rows are in alphabetic order.    btw, Without the malloc char **cast, Visual c compiler gives an error saying a cast is needed.

Comment: Here's the error:  error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char **'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your char filelist[4095][100] example is not the same as your allocation in allocateFileListArray, an array of pointers is not the same as an array of an array.
You should change the compare function for qsort like

```
int compareStrings(const void *stackA, const void *stackB)
{
  const char *a=*(const char**)stackA;
  const char *b=*(const char**)stackB;
  return strcmp(a,b);
}
```

and you can use this function without ugly cast in qsort.

Comment: That does it.  As an aside, why do the arguments to compareStrings() need to be "const"?

Comment: see prototype for the callback-compare function in qsort; you should never ignore a const qualifier

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
void sortTheArray(void)
{
    qsort (fileList, arraySize, sizeof(char *), (compfn) compareStrings );
}
```

?

Have a look a the definition of qsort and pass the parameters accordingly.

If that does not work, have a look at compareStrings(). Do you have one level of indirection too much or too less? Because there is no information about compareStrings(), it is impossible to say, if it has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with 2D allocated int arrays. That is an array of pointers to malloced space. There are a couple tricky components:

1) pointer casting in the compare function, as @user411313 mentioned, it's a pointer to a pointer so you must dereference twice to get the value

2) the size you pass to qsort. The size is the size of a pointer, and not the column count of the 2D array (as is the case with var[row][col]).